# pandas dataframe concatenate strings from a subset of columns and put them into a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I tried to retrieve strings from a subset of columns from a `DataFrame`, concatenate the strings into one string, and then put these into a list,

```
# row_subset is a sub-DataFrame of some DataFrame
sub_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
string_list = [""] * row_subset.shape[0]
for x in range(0, row_subset.shape[0]):
    for y in range(0, len(sub_columns)):
        string_list[x] += str(row_subset[sub_columns[y]].iloc[x])
```

so the result is like,

```
['row 0 string concatenation','row 1 concatenation','row 2 concatenation','row3 concatenation']
```

I am wondering what is the best way to do this, more efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need select columns by subset by `[]` first and then [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) or if need separator use `join`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':list('qwerty'),
                   'C':list('fertuj'),
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  q  f  1  5  a
1  b  w  e  3  3  a
2  c  e  r  5  6  a
3  d  r  t  7  9  b
4  e  t  u  1  2  b
5  f  y  j  0  4  b
```

---

```
sub_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
print (df[sub_columns].sum(axis=1).tolist())
['aqf', 'bwe', 'cer', 'drt', 'etu', 'fyj']

print (df[sub_columns].apply(' '.join, axis=1).tolist())
['a q f', 'b w e', 'c e r', 'd r t', 'e t u', 'f y j']
```

Very similar numpy solution:

```
print (df[sub_columns].values.sum(axis=1).tolist())
['aqf', 'bwe', 'cer', 'drt', 'etu', 'fyj']
```